# Удаление данных в FireBase с Recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, firebase

Добрый день!
Я вывожу данные в Recyclerview и пытаюсь их удалить в FireBase.
Мой код
    package com.sergeev.notes;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.List;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference Refer;

FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

//FirebaseListAdapter Adapt;
private List<String> DicsrTasks;
private EditText Etask;
private Button Btask;

   // ListView UserTasks;

private static class TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView TitleTask;
    Button bEnd;

    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TitleTask = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TTitleTask);
        bEnd = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Finish);
    }
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment, container, false);

    //UserTasks = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.TaskList);

    Refer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //Adapt = new FirebaseListAdapter <String>(getActivity(), String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Refer.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks")) {
     /*   @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String s, int position) {
            TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText(s);

        }
    };
    UserTasks.setAdapter(Adapt);
    */
    Btask = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Add);
    Etask = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.New);

    Btask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Refer.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks").push().setValue(Etask.getText().toString());
            Etask.setText("");
        }
    });

    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvList);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, TaskViewHolder> adapter;

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, TaskViewHolder>(
            String.class,
            R.layout.task_layout,
            TaskViewHolder.class,
            Refer.child(user.getUid()).child("Tasks")
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(TaskViewHolder viewHolder, String title, final int position) {
            viewHolder.TitleTask.setText(title);
            viewHolder.bEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);
                    itemRef.removeValue(null);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;


}


}
```

Когда я удаляю первый раз любой элемент, он удаляется. Затем когда я пытаюсь удалить элемент после него (например удалили 1 и пытаемся удалить элемент 2), то удаляется 3 элемент (следующий) И постоянно или через 2 удаляется или через 3, но тот который нужен. Видимо список сдвигается при удалении одного элемента. Подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку, чтобы удалялся нужный элемент, а не иной другой.
Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Скорее всего потому что не нужно использовать модификатор `final` для позиции в адаптере. Попробуйте в клик листенере использовать `viewHolder. getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: А если по подробнее, в какой фрагмент вставить viewHolder. getAdapterPosition()? Его добавить или заменить? Кстати, если Вы про final int position, то здесь без final выдаётся ошибка

Comment: В клик листенере вместо `DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);` напишите `DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(viewHolder. getAdapterPosition());` и тогда никакой ошибки без `final` не будет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы используете `position` из метода `populateViewHolder` в клик листенере, который будет вызван в неопределённый момент. Как сказано в 
[документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)), данный метод адаптера не вызывается при изменении позиции элемента в наборе данных, то есть при удалении элемента в клик листенере остаётся старое значение `position`.

Чтобы этого избежать, используйте метод вью холдера `getAdapterPosition()`, который всегда возвращает актуальную позицию:

```
viewHolder.bEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        itemRef.removeValue(null);
    }
});
```